# Using stored procedure to login Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures

I'm using asp.net to create a login page; in debugging I see the correct inputted data but I keep gettting the error message  Invalid Username or Password even when it is valid. I have also executed the stored procedure with values and shows the correct result. I'm not sure what is happening.

```
 protected void login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String username = txtUserName.Text.ToString();
            String password = txtPassword.Text;
            string con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LoginConnectionString"].ToString();
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(con);
            connection.Open();

        string passwords = encryption(password);

        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("spLogin", connection);
        cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", username);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", passwords);
        SqlDataReader sqldr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
        if (sqldr.Read())
        {
            Session["UserName"] = username.ToUpper();
            Response.Redirect("~/Home/Welcome.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            lblError.Text = "Invalid Username or Password";

        }

        connection.Close();
        sqldr.Close();

    }
```

StoredProcedure

```
    select * from Users u  where UserName=@UserName and password=@password
```

Comment: it seems that the user u r checking is not in the DB

Comment: @Coding but the user is actually in the DB; it worked when I insert the same user in the SP

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint on the method? Is client-side validation stopping it?

Comment: @IrishChieftain; yes I did set breakpoints and I see the correct value but then it throws the error message Invalid Username or Password

Comment: Check the connection string in your Web.config. The error message is self-explanatory ;-)

Comment: I did check that; but I execute the stored procedure the doesn't show the return values. Return value 0 Message: 1 row affected. maybe something wrong with the stored procedure

Comment: Where is it throwing the error and why are you converting the user name to upper case?